# Firebase Google Login Failed

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase Google Sign In. It was working fine until i upload my app to the play store. I am getting Sign In Failed Problem. Another problem that i am facing with when a user successfully signs in it returns :

> bad getToken() -> BAD_AUTHENTICATION. Account.

```java
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
            GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
            assert account != null;

            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
        } else {
            // check internet connection, display a message to the user.
            Toast.makeText(LRActivity.this, "Signin Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the token request :

```java
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
    .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
    .requestEmail()
    .requestScopes(new Scope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube")) // you can request scope here OR at the time of subscribe
    .build();
```

Comment: your app is working on debug mode but not working on live mode is this right ?

Comment: Yes. @SandeepMalik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow [this link](https://www.appdome.com/no-code-mobile-integration-knowledge-base/extracting-a-sha-1-fingerprint-from-the-google-play-app-signing-certificate/) to get a `SHA` from play store console and update it on your firebase console.

And then you don't need to update a new apk on your console.

There will be 3 SHA1 on your firebase console :

- Debug SHA1.
- Release SHA1.
- Play Store Console SHA1.

Comment: can you tell me why i am getting this error : getToken() -> BAD_AUTHENTICATION. Account ?

Comment: because of the when you do your app live on play store it creates a sha-key to connect with your app after that you have to copy that key from play console and add in firebase console then it will work fiine

Comment: i am getting this getToken() -> BAD_AUTHENTICATION. Account error all the time . In the debug mode and in the live mode also.

Comment: replace your google-services.json file with new google-services.json file and try. Download latest google-services.json file from firebase console

Comment: Can i add 3 sha 1 code in firebase? Like 1 is for playstore , 1 is for release apk and 1 is for direct debug?

Comment: yes, you have to do it. otherwise, you will face problem in google login.